# how to reserve non-paged memory in windows kernel like virtualalloc in ring 3

Tags: windows, kernel, dynamic-memory-allocation

In windows ring 3, we can use `VirtualAlloc` to reserve a region of paged memory and choose to commit as needed. What I'm asking is if there exists a similar api in ring 0 kernel that can reserve non-paged memory.

Now I have been searching the use of `ExAllocatePoolWithTag` and don't have any useful results.

Answer (score 0):

ExAllocatePool*() APIs is the right way to go, with NonPagedPoolNx Pool.

More Information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/allocating-system-space-memory

can you see an example for that in Microsoft Driver samples:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/0b22a5da3df0d570a39681ffdd256cd876c30047/serial/serenum/log.c#L149